# Digital Logic current flow IFF current in different circuit

Tags: digital-logic

Using only digital logic gates, how do you make it so a path is only open for current to go through if there is current flowing through a different part of a circuit.

Specifically, block current from flowing through a circuit until there is (a much weaker) current flowing through a section of a different circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a tri state buffer.

Here is an example of a real-world part: [from texas instruments](http://www.ti.com/product/cd74hct125)

The part I have linked is active low, however. The current flowing in this case would be the leakage current into/out of the control pin. This current can be thought of as controlling the 'path' for the main current to flow through.

---

Additional:
[Wikipedia entry on 3-state logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic)

The high impedance output is the state that 'blocks' current.

Comment: How could I build an active high tri state buffer from transistors and resistors etc?

Comment: Well that is a bit more involved. A tri state buffer should be a first class logic gate in my world but I think you could hack it with simple logic-level n-channel mosfet parts. Here is a link to some parts: http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/n-channel-logic-level-gate-fets/16119